# "the proposal for" or "the proposal of"

Tags: prepositions

I need to prepare the title of a document.

I am not sure whether it should sound like this:

*"The proposal **for** implementation of a new architecture"*

or

*"The proposal **of** implementation of a new architecture"*

The meaning is that we are asking for permission to implement a new architecture in our system (application) and we are explaining how this process should look like.

Comment: Put simply, *proposal for* = documentation & presentation; *proposal of* = "May I?"

Comment: It's a proposal *of* Fred's *for* implementing...

Comment: Are you by any chance making a proposal *to implement* a new architecture? Has it yet been decided that a new architecture will even be implemented?

Comment: Exactly, it has not been decided yet. We want to implement the new architecture and we are asking for permission to go ahead. Is the title all right?

Comment: I would use "...proposal *to*..." instead of "... proposal *for* ...," and have left a comment suggesting that SimonWhite revise his answer. For posterity, you might clarify in your question that this proposal suggests that something *should* be done, not just *how* it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

The title would typically be:

> A Proposal for Implementation of a New Architecture

Ideally you would add one more word to describe what kind of architecture you are referring to. For example:

> A Proposal for Implementation of a New Computing Architecture

But the above are a bit antique and a bit formal for some uses. You might want this:

> Proposal for Implementing a New Computing Architecture

… especially in American English.

Comment: I don't mind it being formal. So it should be "A" instead of "The" at the beginning?

Comment: Dear @Catidew, I agree with SimonWhite's example of using "A" for the first word, even if yours is the only proposal at hand, unless this proposal is already an established topic of discussion and people are waiting for it, which is part of what "The" would imply. Even then, "the" can sound somewhat too imperative compared to the advisory nature of a proposal.

Answer (score 0):

This adds to SimonWhite's
[answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/304618/153448)
in light of Catidew's (OP's) clarifying comment:

> We want to implement the new architecture
>   and we are asking for permission to go ahead.

Consider this title:

> Proposal **to Implement** a New Computing Architecture

- Stating “to implement,” instead of
  “for implementing,” shows that
  you are primarily proposing to do something instead of doing nothing.
  That you are as well offering a description of what to do is implied.
- As SimonWhite indicated, there is no need to start with
  “A” or “The” before “Proposal,”
  just as a dictionary need not be titled
  titled *A Dictionary* or *The Dictionary*,
  though “A Proposal” fits the suggestive and advisory
  nature of a proposal better than does “The Proposal,”
  if you want to choose between the two.